# Modificar características XML através do Java

Tags: java, android, xml

Tenho o seguinte `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_avancado"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/avancado_ttv"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:padding="10dp">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Como posso modificar os atributos `android:layout_below` e `android:visibility` utilizando Java? É possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar uma classe chamada LayoutParams, de acordo com o seu layout (no caso, um RelativeLayout). Para adicionar regras, você utiliza o método `addRule()`, por exemplo:

```
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);

//Crie seu LayoutParams, passando como parametro seu Width e Height
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

//Defindo como BELOW de algum componente, passando o mesmo como parametro
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.yourComponentID);

/*Voce tambem pode definir margins, passando consecutivamente: left, top, right e bottom
* Detalhe que aqui, você passa em PIXELS.
*/
params.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 8);

//Para definir alinhamentos
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

E agora, definindo esses seus novos parametros para o seu componente:

```
mRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Lembrando que, quando você coloca um novo LayoutParams para o seu componente, ele substituí as regras que você colocou via XML.

Para definir a visibilidade, você precisa simplesmente:

```
//Aqui você pode utilizar VISIBLE, INVISIBLE e GONE
mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Cara, a visibilidade eu sei que é possível sim. Basta você usar o findViewById no layout e depois usar o setVisibility, da seguinte forma:

```
findViewById(R.id.layout_avancado).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

A resposta está incompleta, o android:layout_bellow não sei como fazer, outra pessoa que souber responde.

Comment: Acredito que para o `layout_below` é só remover a regra antiga (`removeRule`) e adicionar a nova (`addRule`) no `LayoutParams` e depois chamar o `requestLayout` para atualizar a interface.